# cakephp routing - pages_controller/home.ctp error only on debug=0

Tags: cakephp

When core.php debug is set at 1 or 2 and I browse to the root of my cakephp site I get expected result, the page served is correct, ie, PagesController default() action -> home.ctp

However if I change debug to 0 I get the the following error:

> Error:  The requested address '/' was
>   not found on this server.

My router.php file contains:

```
    Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home'));
/**
 * ...and connect the rest of 'Pages' controller's urls.
 */
    Router::connect('/pages/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));
```

I have tried deleting all cache files and removing CAKE cookies, and other actions work as expected when visited directly, eg, /user, /groups, etc. Problem only occurs when hitting the root '/'.

I am using cakephp 1.3.4 and ACL + Auth.

Edit ** I'm including the code for the default() function from pages_controller.php

```
/**
 * Displays a view
 *
 * @param mixed What page to display
 * @access public
 */
    function display() {

        $path = func_get_args();

        $count = count($path);
        if (!$count) {
            $this->redirect('/');
        }
        $page = $subpage = $title_for_layout = null;

        if (!empty($path[0])) {
            $page = $path[0];
        }
        if (!empty($path[1])) {
            $subpage = $path[1];
        }
        if (!empty($path[$count - 1])) {
            $title_for_layout = Inflector::humanize($path[$count - 1]);
        }
        $this->set(compact('page', 'subpage', 'title_for_layout'));
        $this->render(implode('/', $path));

    }
```

Comment: Is the PagesController::display() allowed in your ACL/Auth? Do you have any "debug ifs" left in your code?

Comment: I have the following in my app/app_controller.php:        $this->Auth->allowedActions = array('display','logout'); and the only place that config::write('debug',...) is used is in core.php

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OK the answer is so simple it is embarassing: in home.ctp there is the following code:

```
if (Configure::read() == 0):
    $this->cakeError('error404');
endif;
```

Configure::read() by default read var debug - therefore it throws this error if debug is set to 0.

Thanks to Benjamin for putting me on the right track. Cake is wonderful and at the same time infuriating until you know the basics!

Comment: for cakephp 2.4.3 above code is replaced with 
if(!Configure::read('debug')):
  throw new NotFoundException();
endif; 
but the issue still exist :P

Answer (score 4):

imho this behavior makes sense, as you turn debug to 0 if your app goes into production (something tells me, that you don't want to show the *home* page as your entry page). The home.ctp which is displayed by the pages controller lives in

`./cake/libs/view/pages/home.ctp`

of your installation. But if you are in production you want to display the static pages from the

`./app/views/pages`

directory, which is the task of the pages controller. This directory is empty in a fresh cake installation.

Comment: +1, nice catch, that's probably it. I remember this was not a case a while ago, but someone reported it as a potential security issue.

Comment: I already copied pages_controller.php from cake/config/controller into app/controller, and I copied home.ctp to app/views/pages. When debug > 0 the page served is definitely app/views/page/home.ctp, but when debug=0 I get the error. I have not altered the default() action in pages_controller.php that comes with standard cake install. I'm not quite sure what happens in that function but maybe something in there is affected by the change in debug value? I'm not sure I can post code into a comment so I'm editing the question to include the code for the default() action.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to update code for cakephp version 2.4.3.
as on cakephp version above code is replaced with

```
if (!Configure::read('debug')):
  throw new NotFoundException();
endif;
```

as when debug is set to '0' it throws exception. you can use below code to make it run properly:

```
if ((Configure::read('debug')==='')):
throw new NotFoundException();
endif;
```