# Error when debug is 0, no error if higher

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I'm in the process of standing up a new CakePHP project with some very simple boilerplate code. In the process of helping a co-working install the code, I realized that if my `debug` value is 0, I get a 404 error (just loading the homepage):

```
Error: The requested address '/' was not found on this server.
```

If I flip the `debug` value to 1 or 2, the error goes away and the default homepage (I don't have any custom layout/page created yet) loads happily. This isn't an ajax request and there's nothing fancy going on here. Anyone seen this before? Haven't found anything via Google that matches what I'm seeing.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

And, just in case anyone is thinking the obvious, my homepage (/) route is configured. Like most everything else, my `routes.php` file hasn't been modified yet.

Comment: where do you set the debug level?

Comment: Originally in `core.php`, but then I override it in `bootstrap.php`. Meaning that in `core.php`, the value is set to 0, but in my `bootstrap.php` I flip it to whatever I need so I can leave `core.php` alone.

Comment: +1 votes just to ease your pain & suffering from the crushing facepalm...  and VTC as dupe of the question you linked.

Comment: @Farray, I appreciate the sympathy upvote. Rough week, rougher day yesterday. Hopefully my geek karma improves in the coming days. :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [cakephp routing - pages_controller/home.ctp error only on debug=0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794063/cakephp-routing-pages-controller-home-ctp-error-only-on-debug-0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh, my. Talk about a punitive headslap moment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3803076/1665

What a long week. I'll mark this answered as soon as the time limit expires. Sheesh...

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting tmp files located at `/app/tmp/cache/`.

I found solution to similar problem here:

http://cakephp.1045679.n5.nabble.com/Re-Not-found-error-with-DEBUG-0-td1257613.html

Comment: Cache is disabled and that directory is empty.