# Different routing behaviour according to debug level

Tags: cakephp, routes

I have a cake php site which lives in a subdirectory on my site called secure, so

```
https://example.com/secure
```

When the debug level is 1 or 2 then it works fine, but if I change the debug level to 0 (with `Configure::write('debug', 0);`) and go to that address I get this error:

```
Error: The requested address '/secure/index.php/secure/' was not found on this server.
```

I have the following two routes in routes.php

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home'));
Router::connect('/secure', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home'));
```

How can I get it to work with debug set to 0? I could move the whole site into example.com, but I'd like that to be a last resort.

Comment: Please always mention your exact CakePHP version and tag your question accordingly!

Comment: possible duplicate of [cakephp routing - pages\_controller/home.ctp error only on debug=0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794063/cakephp-routing-pages-controller-home-ctp-error-only-on-debug-0)

Answer (score 1):

Routing is not being affected by the debug level.

Your problem is that you are pointing the route to the `home` page, which is only available in debug mode because it reveals possibly sensitive system information, see `app/View/Pages/home.ctp`

```
if (!Configure::read('debug')):
    throw new NotFoundException();
endif;
```

Test your routes with a custom page and everything should work fine.