# Cakephp 3.0 NotFoundException home.ctp on production server

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I just deployed a basic version of a CakePHP application. Nothing special or fancy here. Just a basic authorisation module and a couple of baked Controllers.
However when I try to open the website a Not Found error appears. Here is what the error log shows:

```
2015-04-13 21:14:07 Error: [Cake\Network\Exception\NotFoundException] Not Found
Request URL: /
Stack Trace:
#0 /home/public_html/site.com.au/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/View/View.php(815): include()
#1 /home/public_html/site.com.au/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/View/View.php(775): Cake\View\View->_evaluate('/home/pub...', Array)
#2 /home/public_html/site.com.au/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/View/View.php(463): Cake\View\View->_render('/home/pub...')
#3 /home/public_html/site.com.au/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Controller/Controller.php(575): Cake\View\View->render('home', NULL)
#4 /home/public_html/site.com.au/src/Controller/PagesController.php(57): Cake\Controller\Controller->render('home')
#5 [internal function]: App\Controller\PagesController->display('home')
#6 /home/public_html/site.com.au/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Controller/Controller.php(404): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#7 /home/public_html/site.com.au/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Routing/Dispatcher.php(114): Cake\Controller\Controller->invokeAction()
#8 /home/public_html/site.com.au/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Routing/Dispatcher.php(87): Cake\Routing\Dispatcher->_invoke(Object(App\Controller\PagesController))
#9 /home/public_html/site.com.au/webroot/index.php(37): Cake\Routing\Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(Cake\Network\Request), Object(Cake\Network\Response))
#10 {main}
```

Any clues? mod_rewrite is enabled. The login page is working but not the homepage. 
My AppController has this filter:

```
public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
{
    $this->Auth->allow(array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));
}
```

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

In cakephp 3.0 this is the code that needs to be removed from the home.ctp file

```
if (!Configure::read('debug')):
  throw new NotFoundException();
endif;
```

Comment: Please check link:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794063/cakephp-routing-pages-controller-home-ctp-error-only-on-debug-0. i hope the marked answer and the answer have 4 vote up will resolve your problem